# MultiHandleSliderExtender could not be set on property MultiHandleSliderTargets

Tags: c#, asp.net, slider

Here's my code:

```
<asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="TextBox1_MultiHandleSliderExtender" 
runat="server" Enabled="True" HandleAnimationDuration="0.1" Maximum="100" 
Minimum="0" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
<MultiHandleSliderTargets>
<asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="TextBox2" />
<asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="TextBox3" />
</MultiHandleSliderTargets>
</asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

When I add MultiHandleSliderTargets the design view shows me the error written above, how ever  the error is gone when I remove the MultiHandleSliderTargets. But if I don't specify targets how am I supposed to get value in the targeted boxes... Help Plz

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the ControlID's of the MultiHandleSliderTargets with the full TextBox IDs.

In my case the textboxes are placed in one of these:

`<asp:Content ID="ContentHolder" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">`

So their full Control ID's would be ctl00_MainContent_TextBox2 and ctl00_MainContent_TextBox3

Your textbox ID's maybe slightly different depending on what they're nested in but hopefully you get the idea.

```
<asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender ID="TextBox1_MultiHandleSliderExtender" 
runat="server" Enabled="True" HandleAnimationDuration="0.1" Maximum="100" 
Minimum="0" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
<MultiHandleSliderTargets>
<asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="ctl00_MainContent_TextBox2" />
<asp:MultiHandleSliderTarget ControlID="ctl00_MainContent_TextBox3" />
</MultiHandleSliderTargets>
</asp:MultiHandleSliderExtender>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I'm not using MasterPage or ContentHolder so the IDs of my TextBoxes should be simple like TextBox2 and TextBox3.